# If was not alert go to url else do not go

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make validation jquery **without using from plugin**, problem is here that after click on button and get alert(if field is empty) it go to url `#` that there is in `<form action="#"...`.

I want if get alert(mean if field is empty) 'input is empty' not go to url that there is in `...action="#"...`, if filed has value it go to url. i can not use from `ajax call` or `preventDefault` or `window.location`(Because one from field is `input:file`).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gb7nh/1/

How can fix it?

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button id="cli">Submit</button>
</form>


$('#cli').live('click',function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        if($('input[type="text"]').val()=='')alert('input is empty')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to form submittal instead, and return false to prevent the form from submitting.

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button id="cli">Submit</button>
</form>

$('#myform').submit(function() {
  var valid = true;

  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      alert('A field is empty!');
      valid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!valid) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This just work for first fild, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jGu4e/  i want it work for all fields.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to loop through all the text fields. I have updated my answer to reflect that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
<button id="cli" onclick="return clickButton();">Submit</button>
```

And it's corresponding JavaScript

```
function clickButton(){
    if($('input[type="text"]').val()==''){
        alert('input is empty');
        return false;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to `return false` in case when you show alert woth errors:

```
$('#cli').live('click',function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    if($('input[type="text"]').val()=='')
    {
        alert('input is empty');
        return false;
    }

});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/gb7nh/2/

Answer (score 0):

I wolud do it like Elliot. Only i would have used:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button id="cli">Submit</button>
</form>

$('#myform').submit(function() {
   if (!$('input[type="text"]').val()) {
     alert('input is empty');
      return false;
   }
});
```

This.

```
if (!$('input[type="text"]').val())
```

Instead of:

```
if ($('input[type="text"]').val()=='')
```

Comment: This just work for first fild, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jGu4e/  i want it work for all fields.